# Расположение элементов по кругу Android

Tags: android, adapter

Нужен адаптер который будет располагать элементы по кругу. Если кто нибудь имеет представление о том как это сделать поделитесь идеями или линками если где-то такое уже есть.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду "по кругу" ?? Визуально или вы говорите про вечную прокрутку  ??

Comment: Стандартный будильник в Android 4.4. В нем радиальный селектор времени (radial time selector in the Clock app).  Можно найти исходники и попытаться разобраться.

Comment: адаптер не располагает элементы на экране, а только наполняет айтемы данными, ничего не зная о их "географическом" положении. Расположением айтемов на экране занимается виджет (например ListView). Такого типа виджета с адаптером мне встречать не приходилось, его реализация выглядит весьма проблематичной и понадобится писать компонент практически с нуля, так как ничего похожего в SDK, от чего можно было бы наследоваться, нет. Можно попробовать на базе `GridView` что то придумать, наверное.